# Specialty tool needed for Stihl muffler removal

Tags: lawn, engine, chainsaw

I have a Stihl chainsaw MS 181 CB-E part number 1139-011-3012 and need to remove the muffler to check the spark arrestor. The bolts holding it on are either a proprietary or security head. Does anyone know what tool is needed to be able to remove the muffler? My assumption is this is to guard against modification.

[image: Muffler]

Comment: Could you show us a picture of the bolts?

Comment: A quick search for your model number plus "parts" gave me [this page](https://www.diyspareparts.com/parts/stihl/diagrams/ms181-c/78772758-9a02-4931-a0fc/) which shows a listing of tools available from Stihl for that saw. Nothing special about a couple of sockets, flat blade screwdrivers or an Allen key/hex wrench. We'll _really_ need a _very_ clear, focused pic of the bolts in question in order to determine if it's really something special.

Comment: Google search for muffler removal calls for using a T-27 driver, (a torx screwdriver).  Check for yourself incase I goofed.

Comment: I just added muffler removal.  The allen keys in your comment link probably are torx type also.

Comment: Photo added for clarity.

Comment: Do those eared disks turn with fingers? Either they're some sort of springy retainer or that's not how the muffler comes off.

Comment: Those are not torx screws/bolts.  My earlier comment seems to be not quite right, with seeing the picture.

Comment: @user1451630 please remove your edit and post it as an answer. This is a Question & Answer site, not a general discussion forum, and it'll help others to know that this has an answer instead of just being yet another unanswered question.

Answer (score 6):

After staring at my photo for a few minutes I realized these are just plugs. After prying out the plugs the Torx bit presented its self.

Comment: I knew it! Just clips.